# A word to describe a plain house which also implies admiration

Tags: word-choice

Please help me to find a word to describe a plain/severe house which also implies admiration.

Can I say **"a sincere home"**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say "a modest home".

> **mod·est** *(mŏd′ĭst)*
>   
> *<sup>adj.</sup>*
> 4. Free from showiness or ostentation; unpretentious.
> <sub>Source: [Definition of “modest” on thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/modest)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Sincere is an attribute ascribed to people.

How about "charming"?

Comment: Thank you codenoire. But I think it wouldn't connote plain.

Answer (score 3):

Houses in Jane Austen books are often described as "handsome".  It means a nice looking building, of a good size, but not one with a lot of ornamentation.  "Well-proportioned" might work too, it stresses that the overall effect of the house is pleasing, but not because of any particular decoration.

In my American dialect, I hear "sincere" and think "that's a polite way of saying small".  Same with "modest".  I don't think "homey" or "rustic" are what you want, those aren't admirable qualities.

Answer (score 2):

No, I wouldn't.  Try going to the thesaurus and looking up "homey" and "rustic".

Comment: Thank you BodRodes. "Homey" is great but I think "modest" fits better in my sentence.

Comment: Modest is a good word indeed, but for lack of a better one it's a bit overused.  See http://www.listener.co.nz/commentary/the-internaut/20-cliches-of-journalism/ for an amusing take on this.  Don't miss the response at the bottom for "modest, well-kept home" (means at least the cockroaches are dead).